# Programatically Extract zip file- Xamarin MAC

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

We are on the way to develop cross platform application using XAMARIN.
We are successfully created the ipad version of the application using Xamarin.iOS.
Now we are on the way to develop the MAC version of the same application.
In this application we have Zip file extraction part.  For iPad version we had used  “ZipArchive” . Unfortunately the “ZipArchive” does not support in “Xamarin.MAC”.

I am stuck with this issue.
 Does anybody know, how to solve this issue?
Please let me know if you have a solution.

Thanks

Ranish